# Create custom groovy closure to reuse shell() feature

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using Groogy DSL plugin in my Jenkins server. I realize this step is repeated in many places and jobs.

```
steps {
    shell('''#!/bin/bash -ex
        |aws s3 cp s3://${STACK_S3_BUCKET_NAME}/file myfile --region ${AWS_REGION}
        |aws s3 cp s3://${STACK_S3_BUCKET_NAME}/otherfile .
        |
        |'''.stripMargin())
```

I am new using Groovy and I will like to create kind of custom Groovy Step or Closure to avoid this process, I will like to do something like:

```
awsS3cp {
    from: '${ORIGIN}'
    to: '${DESTINATION}'
    }
```

Then implement something like this:

```
def awsS3cp { context -> 
    shell('''#!/bin/bash -ex
            |aws s3 cp s3://$from $to
            |'''.stripMargin())
    }
```

### Attempt 1

I did it in this way and it failed:

```
def awsS3cp(String from, String to) {
      shell("""#!/bin/bash -ex
            |echo 'copy from $from to $to'
            |""".stripMargin())
}

def createEnvironmentJob = freeStyleJob( jobName )

createEnvironmentJob.with{
    description( jobDescription )
    steps {
     awsS3cp ("S3-SOURCE-BUCKET","S3-TARGET-BUCKET") 
    }
}
```

The error output:

```
No signature of method: create_environment.shell() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [#!/bin/bash -ex
echo 'copy from S3-SOURCE-BUCKET to S3-TARGET-BUCKET'
]
Possible solutions: queue(java.lang.String), sleep(long), every(), grep(), job(java.lang.String), queue(javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to define a function outside:

```
def awsS3cp(String from, String to) {
  return sh("""#!/bin/bash -ex
            |aws s3 cp s3://$from $to
            |""".stripMargin())
}
```

Then, call it inside of the pipeline definition:

```
steps {
    awsS3cp('source', 'destination')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is possible to move that to a helper function and reused in all of my Jenkins job definitions?

Comment: @Robert yes, that is what you can use [_Shared Libraries_](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) for.